# Error at importing the library graphql-upload in a NestJS with GraphQL application

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, graphql-upload

I'm trying to use the library graphql-upload into my application of nestJs with graphQL and when I import the library I get this error:

> Module '"graphql-upload"' has no exported member 'GraphQLUpload'.

This is how I import the library:

```
import { GraphQLUpload } from 'graphql-upload';
```

Also I mantion the versions I'm using maybe the problem could be there:

```json
"graphql-upload": "^16.0.2",
"@types/graphql-upload": "^16.0.0",
"graphql": "^16.6.0",
"@types/node": "18.11.18",
"@nestjs/graphql": "^11.0.0",
"@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",

"typescript": "^4.7.4"
```

To find a solution, i've tried to change verions of graphql-upload, graphql etc, I also tried to import the library in other ways such as:

```
const {
  GraphQLUpload,
  Upload,
  graphqlUploadExpress, // A Koa implementation is also exported.
} = require('graphql-upload');
```

Comment: see that to know more https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-upload/issues/318

Answer (score 0):

The problems is comming from your imports they need to be like that:

`import GraphQLUpload from 'graphql-upload/GraphQLUpload.js';`

`import Upload  from "graphql-upload/Upload";`